# Dont know how to create an object of a class that contains a template class

Tags: c++

I am studying for a C++ exam at uni, and I came across an object declaration that I have no idea how to implement.

The gimmick of the problem is that we are given the body of the function, and we need to add classes, member functions, etc. to make it work.

The part I'm stuck at is the GroupOfPeople. I have no idea how to make that class work, or why it has the Description part in <>, since I have never seen that during the creation of an object.

Could someone explain to me why its there and how to do it properly?

```
namespace Task_2{

template<class T, class U>
class Description{
public:
    T first;
    U second;
    Description(T first, U second) : first(first), second(second) {}

};

template<class T, class U>
class GroupOfPeople{
public:
    Description<T, U> desc;
    string name;
    GroupOfPeople(const string &name) : name(name){}
};

void zadatak_2() {

    //**************************************************************************

    // The entire code for task 2 has to be within namespace Task_2
    using namespace Task_2;

    //**************************************************************************

    // Description contains two values (height and hair color) of different types
    Description<int, string> dok1(180, "blue");
    Description<int, string> dok2(172, "black");


    //**************************************************************************
    // GroupOfPeople contains descriptions
    GroupOfPeople<Description<int, string>> group("students");  // name of the group is "students"

/* // adding pairs into the group above

    group.add(dok1);
    group.add(dok2);

// there is more but its not important
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly did you mean, but here is working code

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

namespace Task_2{

template<class T, class U>
class Description{
public:
    T first;
    U second;
    Description() {}
    Description(T first, U second) : first(first), second(second) {}
};

template<class T, class U>
class GroupOfPeople{
public:
    vector<Description<T, U>> descs;
    string name;
    GroupOfPeople(const string &name) : name(name){}
    void add(Description<T, U> description) {
        descs.push_back(description);
    }
};

void zadatak_2() {
    // Description contains two values (height and hair color) of different types
    Description<int, string> dok1(180, "blue");
    Description<int, string> dok2(172, "black");

    //**************************************************************************
    // GroupOfPeople contains descriptions
    GroupOfPeople<int, string> group("students");  // name of the group is "students"

    // adding pairs into the group above
    group.add(dok1);
    group.add(dok2);
}
}
```

Firstly, you should create default constructor for `Description` class because it used in `GroupOfPeople` and it's type was undefined (there was the first problem).
Secondly, I replaced `Description<T, U> desc` inside `GroupOfPeople` with `vector<Description<T, U>> descs` because I saw methods `add(dok1)` and `add(dok2)` in your code, so, I think your class should contains a few Descriptions -> I store them in `vector`.
Hope, it helped you, if any questions - I can answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much, you have no idea how much this helps. This is exactly what I meant, I managed to figure out how to add 1 Description but when I turned it into a vector I got bad_array exceptions.  

So when I'm using a template class in another class I have to have a default constructor?  

And do you have any idea why my professor would write    
`GroupOfPeople<Description<int, string>> group("students");`
and not   
`GroupOfPeople<int, string> group("students");`

Comment: @user18010398, there you should have a default constructor because when you create an object of GroupOfPeople class it implicitly initializes all it's variables. In your case, object group has been trying to initialize variable desc and it caused an error because the object didn't know what are template types T and U

Comment: Also, I really don't know why your professor wrote GroupOfPeople<Description<int, string>> group("students"); because you have template<class T, class U> so you should substitute types T and U when you create an object of class GroupOfPeople (in your case with <int, string>)

Comment: You can write template<class T> class GroupOfPeople and don't use Description class in your second one but replace it just with T. In this way, you can write GroupOfPeople<Description<int, string>> group("students");